# integrar o slick slider ao meu projeto

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

Estou tentando integrar o Slick em meu projeto  Django porem parece que não funciona de forma alguma, se vocês puderem me ajudar dizendo no que estou errando, me ajudaria muito, vou colocar o código base e como estou usando ele.

**base.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css'%}">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-LtrjvnR4Twt/qOuYxE721u19sVFLVSA4hf/rRt6PrZTmiPltdZcI7q7PXQBYTKyf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/scripts.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**HTML**

```
<main class="fundo">
  <div class="fundo-card">
    <div class="fundo-card-img">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/a4/fb/72/a4fb72a710c9322b2ac90f9e329d2f2d.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/80/9d/d7/809dd7a916407c1a6a08f4d5ecbc2e45.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/77/45/9f/77459fcc5a6c9c928b4c537052b22dda.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/98/5f/23/985f2360500626ec119126328f5958b5.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div> 
</main>
```

**CSS**

```
.fundo {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    padding: 3vw;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
}

.fundo .fundo-card {
    width: 35vw; 
    height: 53vw;
    max-height: 75vh;
    max-width: 50vh;
    margin: 3vw;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 0.7vw;
    background-color: #c4c4c4;
    display: inline-flex;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    justify-content: center;
}

.fundo .fundo-card .fundo-card-img{
  width: 90vw; 
  height: 85%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #c26969;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: static;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
  $('.fundo-card-img').slick({

  });
})
```

Eu utilizo o CDN para trazer o Slick para o projeto, mas não faz nenhuma alteração, como se não existisse os código que coloco.
Não sei se é bug ou se estou errando na ordem das coisas, sou iniciante e tenho muito o que aprender ainda.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Se não está passando nenhuma config não precisa do {} como argumento. Mas talvez não seja o problema, acho que vc precisa que cada elemento esteja dentro de uma div.

Aqui um codepen (não é meu) de exemplo:
https://codepen.io/elethompson/pen/GpXXXW

Comment: Obrigado Ricardo, ajudou demais, agora consigo prosseguir!

Answer (score -1):

o método slick() deve ser aplicado ao container onde ficarão os objetos slaidados. No caso em tela, o slick seria aplicado ao "container-fluid". Mas eu não entendi o que seria o html que não é o base, essa main vai dentro da div "container-fluid" ?